# Estimate value with binomial distribution

Tags: estimation, binomial-distribution, density-estimation

We have some compound A diluted in a solution. In 200 trials, we find that when we mix $1$ $\mathrm{mm}^3$ our solution of A with some amount of some compound B, we get a reaction 185 times. How can I find the density of A in the solution?

My first thought was to use an estimator for a binomial distribution, which would have given us the estimate $\hat{p} = 185/200 = 0.925$ but I am lost as to how this can help me find the density of A in the solution.

Comment: Are you talking about the chemical density of A in the solution?

Comment: Is this a stats question or a chemistry question?

Comment: @Peter Flom: I found this question very interesting, because it ponders how to estmate a proportion *p* when it cannot be measured directly, but the observable is instead the outcome of a random experiment related to *p*. Actually, this makes a nice exercise for stats textbooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not specify the preconditions for "a reaction". Let us assume that "a reaction" occurs when the drawn sample of $1\mbox{mm}^3$ contains at least *one* particle of A.

The density $p$ (in terms of particles of A per particles of the dissolver B, not of mass) depends on the number of particles of the dissolver B withim $1\mbox{mm}^3$. Let this number be $N$. Then the probability that your sample of $1\mbox{mm}^3$ does not contain A is $(1-p)^N$. The probability of "a reaction" is the complement, i.e. $1-(1-p)^N$. Your measurement $r=185/200$ is an estimator for this probability. Solving for $p$ yields:

$$r=1-(1-p)^N \quad\Rightarrow\quad \hat{p}=1-(1-r)^{1/N}$$

**Edit:** When at least *m* particles of A are required for "a reaction", $(1-p)^N$ must be replaced with the CDF of the binomial distribution, and the resulting equation can only be solved numerically for *p*, e.g. in R with the builtin function *uniroot* (*r* is the measured "reaction rate"):

```
uniroot(function(p) (1 - r - pbinom(m,N,p)), interval=c(0,1))
```

Comment: There are no conditions. That's why I didn't add it.

Comment: To be more precise: how many particles of A are required for "a reaction" to occur? My above computation assumes that only *one* particle A is required. When n particles are required, you must use a binomial distribution for estimating the probability that at least n particles are in a sample of N particles.

Comment: There are no specifications, so I guess an arbitrary number $m$ particles required would be a good option.

Comment: Note that we have a solution of A in some solvent, and then we pour this with B.

Comment: I have edited my answer to into account the case of *m* required particles for a reaction. This should now solve your problem.